# Change color from plot with GPy package

Tags: python, plot, colors, gpy

I made a plot by combining the GPY and matplotlib packages. However, for some reason I can not change the color of the line and the confidence interval, see code below. I changed the color of the plot to red, but nothing happens. In the package documentation is written that "The methods in GPy.plotting (and child classes GPy.plotting.gpy_plot and GPy.plotting.matplot_dep) are not intended to be called directly, but rather are ‘injected’ into other classes (notably GPy.core.gp.GP).", which I thought could be the cause. However, I do not understand what it means or how to solve it. Can anybody help me change the color of the line and the confidence interval?

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import GPy
import numpy as np
import GPyOpt

X = np.linspace(0.05,0.95,10)[:,None]
Y = -np.cos(np.pi*X) +np.sin(4*np.pi*X) + np.random.randn(10,1)*0.05
k = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=1., lengthscale=1.)
m = GPy.models.GPRegression(X,Y,k)
m.optimize()
m.plot(figsize=(14, 10))
plt.savefig('Gaussian.png', color='r')
```